# ui-router nested states, changing child state causes parent-defined view to reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in my editor project. I have two ui-views, a preview pane and a settings pane.

```
<div ui-view="preview"></div>
<div ui-view="settings"></div>
```

I always want the `preview` view to show `templates/preview.html`.

By default, I want the `settings` view to show `templates/settings/general.html`.

When I click on an item inside of my `preview`, I want to change the `settings` view to show `templates/settings/item.html` **without reloading the `preview` view**.

For now my routing code looks like this:

```
.state('editor.page', {
    url: "/editor/:pageId",
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'preview': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/preview.html',
            controller: 'PreviewController'
        }
    }
})
.state('editor.page.general', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        'settings@editor': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/settings/general.html',
            controller: 'GeneralSettingsController'
        }
    }
})
.state('editor.page.item', {
    url: "^/editor/:pageId/:item";
    views: {
        'settings@editor': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/settings/item.html',
            controller: 'ItemSettingsController'
        }
    }
})
```

Inside my `preview.html`, each item is a link with a `ui-sref` like this:

```
<a ui-sref="editor.page.item({pageId:id, item:$index})">{{item}}</a>
```

When loading the page, I get the expected behavior: the `preview` shows the page as expected and `templates/settings/general.htm` is loaded in the `settings` view.

However, whenever I click on an item, the `settings` view is updated as expected, but the `preview` view is also reloaded, which I don't want. Is there a way to avoid this behavior?